# "Called me" vs "called me out"

Tags: grammar

When to use the first and the second? For example:

> I was walking in the street when someone **called me**. "Hey, is that
>   you?"
>
> I was walking in the street when someone **called me out**. "Hey, is that
>   you?"

Comment: [**call (someone) out**](https://www.google.com/search?q=call+someone+out) is idiomatic and has a different meaning.

Comment: call out usually has a different meaning but according to the dictionary it could be appropriate even in this case, but it implies that someone called out your name loudly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting distinction:

**Called me** - As in shouted toward me from a distance, or called me on the phone implies speaking in a certain way (from a distance that requires any amount of volume), also "called out to me"

**Called me out** - Implies a failed deception (usually friendly) as in "I put a BMW logo on my Toyota, but Jerry called me out."  So, I was trying to impress everyone with my fancy car, but Jerry wasn't fooled and told everyone.

Sometimes less friendly, as in "Jerry called me out after I stole from him" meaning a challenge to a fight.  I think this is an older usage, I've only ever used the first.

So basically, call as in "call someone" is to speak from a distance and call as in "call someone out" implies minor confrontation or disagreement, usually less than violent